# issue with getting TcpClient server response as string

Tags: c#, tcpclient

so long story short, i am trying to develop an application which requires having Tcp Connection to a server. having no previous experiance in this field i ended up with having none of my functions working. so i decided to make  a simple console app just to check my commands and their responses. the part about setting up the connections went well, so does the part about wrting into network stream(i think) but i hit a wall when trying to display server respons:
each time my porgram reaches the line where it has to Encode server respons and WriteLine, my console application goes all black and all texts goes away. can you tell what's wrong with the code i am using?everything up until the part where console trys to display response goes well, i checked. i want to have server's respones as normal strings(if possible i guess...)

```
static void ServerTalk(TcpClient tcpClient,NetworkStream networkStream, StreamWriter streamWriter, StreamReader streamReader)
    {
        //Messaging methods:
        Console.WriteLine("Client: ");
        string message = Console.ReadLine();
        streamWriter.WriteLine(message);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        //Response methode:
        byte[] data = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
        int ret = networkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        string respond = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data).TrimEnd();
        Console.WriteLine("Server: ");
        Console.WriteLine(respond);
        ServerTalk(tcpClient, networkStream, streamWriter, streamReader);
    }
```

Comment: I suspect you are sending nulls at the end of the data which appears as black.  I would terminate the data at the sender with a return ('\n') then at the receive end only print character up to the return.

Comment: what about the recursive call at the end of the method?  How is that supposed to work?

Comment: @HughJones i just putted it so that the whole start thing all over again, since everything that the app is going to do is in that code of block, the rest of the code was all working and one time use, and i don't think i need this app to do anything more beyond this point.

Comment: @jdweng can you explain that more?

Comment: @HughJones yep, i think that's a better idea, thanks

Comment: Ascii encoding sometimes pads ends of streams with null and these null are usually ignored.  Your code may be reading these nulls.  Normally when ascii data is sent there is a termination character(s) so the receive end of the data won't read past the last valid characters.  Verify if you server is sending more bytes than the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

you need to process only ret bytes, you are translating all bytes in the array.

copy to a new array that is 'ret' long and then decode.

```
var retarr = new byte[ret];
Array.Copy(data,retarr,ret);
string respond = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(retarr);
```

More importantly note that this method of tcp communication is not going to work. You are assuming that when you send x bytes in one block you will receive x bytes in one block, this is not so, you can send 1 100 byte message and receive 100 1 byte messages

This means that you task is much more complex. YOu need to devise a way of sending self describing data - so that you know its completely received. classically you send a length followed by the data. You then keep looping in the receive code till you have received that many bytes

Comment: thank's so much for your update, and your right what i am doing is,,, complex, but we all have to start from somewhere.

Comment: if you get stuck again, post another question. Learn to use the vs debugger